# PowerPoint Listbox on Ribbon to select text to be inserted anywhere on slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint, ribbonx

Im trying to find out if it is possible to add a listbox to the top ribbon in PowerPoint (O365). When clicked on the listbox you can select a title and it will add text wherever your curser is on the slide. Im not looking for a listbox on slide itself just drop down on the ribbon. Im happy to use vba or anything that works, just need pointing in the right direction. Thanks, M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) by embedding a custom UI in the open XML document. Use the [Custom UI Editor](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor) for creating a custom UI. Ribbon Extensibility (RibbonX) uses a simple, text-based, declarative XML markup to create and customize the ribbon.

See how [Customize the Office Fluent ribbon by using an Open XML formats file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/customize-the-office-fluent-ribbon-by-using-an-open-xml-formats-file).

You can read more about the ribbon xml controls in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)